# How to insert image or YouTube where I want to in contenteditable div?

Tags: javascript, html, contenteditable

I want to insert image and YouTube where caret is positioned right before insert them. When I don't take any measures, they are inserted the bottom of `<div>` automatically.

What I did is giving unique id to `<p>` in contenteditable `<div>` to grasp where caret is.
But problem is I can't get id for `<p>` in contenteditable `<div>`. I got always get id for contenteditable `<div>`.

That's why I get error.
[This is sample code.](https://jsfiddle.net/hiro14/p3ssLqpr/16/)

Can anyone solve this problem?
I'm not obsessed with this way. My purpose is to insert them where caret is located right before insert.

Comment: i rly want to help you, but i don't understend what is your question... If i understand you, you want make editable paragraph in div. <div class="parent_div" contenteditable="true"><p id="editable">This text can be edited by the user.</p></div>. And in css you can use like class .parent_div, or #editable...

Comment: Thank you for comment. What's your question? I just want to insert image or YouTube where I want to. If I don't put `document.execCommand('defaultParagraphSeparator', false, 'p');`, browser create `div` in contenteditable `div` automatically. I just prefer `p`.